# Render a form in page.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

In my template.php I create a form and then in `hook_preprocess_page` function I assign it to a variable but how to I render it out in `page.tpl.php`

```
$variables['myform'] = drupal_get_form('test_myform');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try add the following line in your `page.tpl.php`

```
print drupal_render($myform);
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: yes  it did. I was not returning $variable['myform'] in the preprocess function.

Comment: Putting that in your page.tpl.php file will have strange results...try submitting the form with some incorrect values and you'll notice the error messages aren't displayed, even though the fields are highlighted in red. Then refresh the page and voila, the messages will appear. You should do the rendering in the preprocess function, or even better in a custom module